# Can't capture QkeyEvent in QopenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a problem about capturing `QKeyEvent` in a `QOpenGLWidget` when I use it as a... widget. It works perfectly well if I use my `QOpenGLWidget` as a main window but not if the widget is the child of another mainWindow... (Nothing happen)

Maybe I messed up something about how Qt widgets works but I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: I have two ideas either :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `yourGLWidget->setFocusPolicy (Qt::StrongFocus);`

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop: *"You must enable keyboard focus for a widget if it processes keyboard events. This is normally done from the widget's constructor."*

Comment: It works by setting it from the constructor. Btw it doesn't when I try to set it from the window designer... nevermind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess either your mainWindow treat the QKeyEvent (maybe it's an already mapped key combination) or prevents the forwarding to your custom widget component. Either when used as "QWidget", special rules are applied and you need to override some others handlers to make your handler able to take place.